# Obtain the offset from a Sql server Datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datetimeoffset

I need to recover a datetime from a table and convert it to a DateTimeOffset, but I need to save these values with their correct offset, not the current offset
For example:

(Spanish timezone example)

- If I recover `2014/04/13 00:00:00`, I need `2014/04/13 00:00:00 +02:00`
- If I recover `2014/02/13 00:00:00`, I need `2014/02/13 00:00:00 +01:00`

I know how to do it with C#, but I need to know if it is possible to do with Sql Server because I have to make a migration with moving a lot of data from a database with datetime fields to a database with datetimeoffset fields.

Thank you very much!

Comment: why is the correct offset for april 13 `+02:00` and for february 13 `+01:00`? And what do you mean by `current offset`?

Comment: What do you want to do with ambiguous times? (i.e. what do you want for `2013-10-27T02:30:00`?)

Comment: On the example I'm working with Spanish time zone so the time change was (this year) on March, 30. This is an example  of a date before and after this change.

Comment: About the ambiguous times, It is a problem I have to resolve yet, but first I want to know if there is an "sql-server way" to make this, or I have to use a CLR function, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle ambiguous times, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned, but here is how you can calculate the offset (assuming your dates are >=1998)

```
SELECT YourDate,
       CASE WHEN YourDate < LocalSummerTimeStart 
                 OR YourDate > LocalSummerTimeEnd
            THEN 1
            ELSE 2
       END AS Offset
FROM YourTable
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT YEAR(YourDate) * 10000 +  300 + (31 - ((((5 * YEAR(Yourdate)) / 4) + 4) % 7)) AS UTCSummerTimeStartDate
               ,YEAR(YourDate) * 10000 + 1000 + (31 - ((((5 * YEAR(YourDate)) / 4) + 1) % 7)) AS UTCSummerTimeEndDate
     ) AS CA1
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DATEADD(hour, 2, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), UTCSummerTimeStartDate), 112)) AS LocalSummerTimeStart
               ,DATEADD(hour, 3, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8), UTCSummerTimeEndDate), 112)) AS LocalSummerTimeEnd
     ) AS CA2
```

[european summer time formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Time_in_Europe)